# Power BI composite/dual mode - SQL DB + SSAS MOLAP

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, ssas

I need to combine two sources: 1. SQL DB (import) + SSAS 2022 Multidimensional (DirectQuery) in one report.
It turns out that the composite model only supports Tabular cubes - do you know any workarounds on how to do this? I work on-prem so no live connection to the dataset in cloud etc.
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the ANSI/ISO SQL _language_, (Perhaps you want to add <sql-server>?)